# VB script for EDI

Tags: sql, vbscript, edi

Amateur coder here. I am working with an EDI system named Syspro that supports VB script for sending and receiving invoices. Our system is having issues attaching the correct SCAC code to the invoice we send out. We our currently fixing this manually by looking at the PO number on the invoice, looking up the PO in Syspro where the SCAC code is shown with other information. We then type the SCAC code into the different lines of the Invoice before we send it out.

What I want to do is automate this with a VB script. It should be pretty simple to do, but I am having trouble understanding the programming logic of VB script in relation to EDI formatting. The overarching logic should look like this:

1) Check to see if there is a SCAC code in each invoice (there are several invoices per file).
2) If SCAC code exists, do nothing. If no SCAC code exist, grab the PO number on the invoice.
3) Run a query with the PO and grabing the associated SCAC code.
4) Inserting the SCAC code into the correct spot in the Invoice.

I really think this would only take 5-10 minutes for someone familiar with VB script and EDI, but to me it's proving very difficult. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad for SO. Perhaps focus on the first step "I have a file that looks like <sample of file> in VB script how would I check to see if the 'SCAC Code' was populated for each 'Invoice'" or something like that. Furthermore, without seeing a sample, and understanding the EDI standard (there are lots of them and some are really strange) that the file is in, it's really close to impossible to help here.

Comment: Syspro is an ERP system with a hacky EDI integration capability.  Changing invoice data on the fly is not really a great practice.  Why not ask the partner(s) to send correct data?